# I have two nested loop after that have a promise call which is important pass through the server in order, but it didn't call in order

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, es6-promise

This is my code
all of them work correctly except this: new forms().saveForm(item, null). It doesn't call in order, forms is prototype in an another js file and I called here.
what should I do to call it in order?

This is my saveform function

```
  const _saveForm = function (model, serverId) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                $.ajax({
                    beforeSend: function () { loadPanel.indicatorShow(); },
                    complete: function () { loadPanel.indicatorHide(); },
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/Publish/AddForms',
                    data: { form: model, serverFormId: serverId },
                }).done((data) => {
                    if (data.HasError) {
                        reject({ state: 'error', content: data });
                    }
                    if (!data.HasError) {
                        resolve({ state: 'done', content: data });
                    }
                }).fail((errorThrown) => {
                    reject({ state: 'fail', content: errorThrown });
                });
            } catch (error) {
                reject({ state: 'error', content: error });
            }
       });

    }

const s_db = new storeDb();
s_db.getBasicFormDataFromDb().then((result) => {
                                return result;
                            }).then((basicForms) => {
                                s_db.getProviderIdsFromDb().then((providerIds) => {
                                    basicForms.forEach(async (item) => {
                                        var arr_field = [];
                                        const _form_fields = item['fields'];
                                        _form_fields.forEach(async fieldItem => {
                                            var jsondata = JSON.parse(fieldItem);
                                            if (jsondata.hasOwnProperty('SelectiveSetting')) {
                                                var replacePId = jsondata.SelectiveSetting.DataProvider.ProviderId;
                                                _.find(providerIds, (k) => {
                                                    if (k['oldId'] === replacePId) {
                                                        jsondata.SelectiveSetting.DataProvider.ProviderId = k['newId'];
                                                        fieldItem = JSON.stringify(jsondata);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                            arr_field.push(fieldItem);
                                        });

                                        item['fields'] = arr_field;
                                        new forms().saveForm(item, null);
                                    })
                                })
                            })
```

Comment: 99% of the time you use `async`/`await` in `forEach` it doesn't do what you expect - use a regular for loop instead

Comment: @Bravo is correct, you are supplying an async function to your `forEach` Loop that simply get calls twice. And as the nature of asynchronous functions is, the then get executed asynchronously

Comment: Not exactly what I sai, nothing to do with `.then` - everything to do with using async/await in forEach is 99% of the time a *bad idea™*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: @Bravo,thanks for your response, I used regular for but it didn't work

Comment: Typo?? `new forms().saveForm(item, null);` => `new forms()._saveForm(item, null);` Looks like you forgot the `_` in `_saveForm`..

Comment: @zahrabanaeian - not in the code you posted, so it's hard to tell what you did wrong

Comment: @Bravo ok, let me describe in this way: Think you have an object  that contains nested list like this: {
  "from": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "arr": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "arr": [
        10,
        8
      ]
    }
  ]
}
  that should  be insert in database in order but before the object inserted I should do something with my "arr" list then insert  my object respectively, like at first item with id=6 insert then second item with id = 1 should be insert.

Comment: you can described it 10 ways from Sunday - doesn't change the fact that async/await in forEach never does what you want -

Comment: @Bravo I understand. but I describe the problem to give me solution if you have

Comment: No, I have no solution to the code you posted in the question